# Authenticate front end application and backend REST API

Tags: javascript, rest, api, express

I have developed a `REST API` and application logic for the `client-side`. Now, both the application logic and `REST API` are separated and not tightly coupled.

I want to implement an authentication system such that after login in from the `client-side`, you will be authenticated automatically both on the `client-side` and the `REST API` side.

**Example:** After login in on the `client-side` user ables to access `photo/add` and `api/photo/add` automatically.

I want to use `cookies` but I don't know if it is feasible and I want to try `JWT` but I have so far read were addressing only either the `client-side` or `front-end` in which the application logic and calls to database are `tightly coupled` or the `REST API` itself alone but not both at the same time.

**In short:** I am saying how do I authenticate views like the pages and the REST API at the time?

Comment: Your question explains what you want, Basically you need to know the alogirthm/way to implement such functionality. Not exactly the code. There are certain industry standard which you can use. But you will need to write some logic on both client and server side. The good thing is you already know about JWT.

Answer (score 1):

to communicate between your client and your API you can use [`AJAX`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/AJAX), for this you can use either

[`the fetch API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)

```js
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
  .then(response => {  
    if (!response.ok) {
      // error handling
      throw new Error('HTTP error, status = ' + response.status);
    }
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(json => console.log(json))
```

or `HMLHttpRequest`

```js
let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest()
xhttp.open('GET', 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1', false); 
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(event) {
    // XMLHttpRequest.DONE === 4
    if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        if (this.status === 200) {
            // worked
            console.log(this.responseText);
        } else {
            // error
            console.log("Status de la réponse: %d (%s)", this.status, this.statusText);
        }
    }
};
xhttp.send(null);
```

---

keeping the connection can be done using cookies or session storage

the main difference is that cookies are sent as HTTP header for each request while localstorage is accessible only with your client js

[`cookie`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) can be accessed in js using `document.cookie` which give a string looking like `name=oeschger; favorite_food=tripe; test1=Hello; test2=World`

[`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) can be accessed with `window.localStorage` which is a [`Storage`](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57412166/edit) object giving 5 methods :

- `Storage.key()`
  When passed a number n, this method will return the name of the nth key in the storage.
- `Storage.getItem()`
  When passed a key name, will return that key's value.
- `Storage.setItem()`
  When passed a key name and value, will add that key to the storage, or update that key's value if it already exists.
- `Storage.removeItem()`
  When passed a key name, will remove that key from the storage.
- `Storage.clear()`
  When invoked, will empty all keys out of the storage.

### the way to keep someone logged in

the way they are ued for auto login is :

- you look if there is a auth token (random unique string) stocked
- if yes you try login using the token

  - if the server accept everything's good
  - if the server refuse you go to the else
- else

  - the user log normally with it's account
  - the server answer with an auth token
  - you store it the way you want

auth token must have a limited lifetime (it's illegal for cookies to live for more than a year in europe)

one token per account max, new token invalidate previous token

more info on the process on https://security.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

> I want to implement an authentication system such that after login in from the client-side, you will be authenticated automatically both on the client-side and the REST API side.

You can achieve this using an industry standard RFC 7519 method [JWT](https://jwt.io/)

Just add [passport](http://www.passportjs.org/) and [passport-jwt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-jwt) to your packages, write a middleware to check, if request has token in headers or query params. If has, check token availability (expire, roles etc.) then, your middleware will automatically serve the requested page.